# An example of a not positive definite sesquilinear form

Tags: riemann-integration, positive-definite, sesquilinear-forms

Let $R\left(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\right)$ denote the space of Riemann integrable periodic functions on $\left[0,1\right]$. 
Let $<\cdot,\cdot>: R\left(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $$<f,g>=\int_0^1f\left(x\right)\overline{g\left(x\right)} dx.$$

The fact that $<\cdot,\cdot>$ is not positive definite is given. I do not understand why.
Can someone help me understanding why is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: @postmortes: your example does not prove or disprove anything. Positive definite means $\langle f,f\rangle >0$ for all non zero $f$.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what it means to be periodic on a bounded interval, but I imagine something like $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x = 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ would work.  We would have $f = 0 \text{ a.e.}$ but not identically $0$ in our space.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f$ to be the $1$-periodic function défined on $[0,1]$ by $f(x)=0$ if $0<x<1$, and $f(0)=f(1)=1$.

Then $f$ is nonzero, but $\langle f,f\rangle=0$.